# Push notification has been successfully forwarded to apns but iPhone does not receive any notification

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

Push notification is getting forwarded to com.notnoop.apns API successfully but does not forward the notification to iPhone. Initially it was working fine and I could able to receive notification from the same code but suddenly it stopped working. Kindly suggest me if you have any idea.

My code :

```
if (!p12File.equals(null) && !password.equals(null)) {
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(p12File).getFile());
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (pushNotification.getPushService().equals("APNS")) {
                ApnsService service = null;
                if (pushNotification.getP12File().equals("dev")) {
                    service = APNS.newService().withCert(file.getAbsolutePath(), password).withSandboxDestination().build();
                } else if (pushNotification.getP12File().equals("dis")) {
                    service = APNS.newService().withCert(file.getAbsolutePath(), password).withProductionDestination().build();
                }
                deleteInactiveDevices(service);
                String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody(pushNotification.getMessage()).alertTitle(pushNotification.getTitleAlert()).
                sound("default").customField("secret", "what do you think?").build();
                String token = pushNotification.getDeviceToken();
                //  System.out.println(service.hashCode());
                service.testConnection();

                ApnsNotification ser = service.push(token, payload);

                System.out.println(ser);
            } else if (pushNotification.getPushService().equals("GCM")) {
                System.out.println("GCM Not implemented");
            }
            message = "Successfully send your push notification message";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        message = "Cannot send your push notification message";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check APNS certificates, Dev Profile, and Provision Profiles.

Comment: We have checked it for p12  we have the validity till 2017 and profiles are perfect

Comment: the written code is in JAVA ? means Backend code ?

Comment: we are pushing the notification from the backend code using java